# JavaScript don't save style properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my site. I want to show a div on button click and hide it on another button click so I use JavaScript functions

```
    function DisplayMessage() {
        var messagebox = document.getElementById("messageConfirmation");
        messagebox.style.display = "block";
    }
    function HideMessage() {
        var messagebox = document.getElementById("messageConfirmation");
        messagebox.style.display = "none";
    }
```

but when I use them `<div>` shows and hides in only a moment, and then appears/disappears again, I really don't know what can cause such a problem so i will be really thankful for your answers. Full HTML page code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        div.wrap {
            width: 850px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        div.messageBox{
            display:none;
            width:500px;
            height:60px;
            background-color: rgb(200, 200, 175);
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function DisplayMessage() {
            var messagebox = document.getElementById("messageConfirmation");
            messagebox.style.display = "block";
        }
        function HideMessage() {
            var messagebox = document.getElementById("messageConfirmation");
            messagebox.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="messageBox" id="messageConfirmation" >
            <p>Message</p>
            <form>
                <button onclick="HideMessage()">HideME</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <button onclick="DisplayMessage()">ShowMe</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `<button>` inside a `<form>` element will act like a `submit` button, so once your code runs, the form is submitted and the page is refreshed, so it goes back to its old state. Change its `type` to `button` in order to achieve what you want:

```
<button type="button" onclick="HideMessage()">HideME</button>
```

Comment: Spot on. Quibble: It's not that it *acts* like a submit button, it's that it *is* a submit button. The default `type` of `button` is `"submit"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your Edit.

Comment: Thanka a lot. You saved my project.

Comment: @MasterUZ Glad to help! Try to press the tick mark present inside this answer as it will help the future visitors to know this answer has helped you. And this is not a compulsion. :) Just telling this, since you are a new user here.